# go back with browser's back button showing previous value

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, salesforce

I am developing a web application in salesforce. I am getting a problem in browser's back button.

I have a web page when i click to submit button that will submit an redirect to second page, Meanwhile i am updating that record during submittion proccess. After that on second page, when i click on browser's back button that redirect to previous page and is still showing previous value. but value is updated in database.

after that when refresh that page with "ctrl+f5" now that is showing actual updated value.

what should be done in thia case. Please any body help me. thanks

Comment: That seems like default browser behavior. try using history.js?

Comment: This is indeed the default behavior of your browser and I’d not recommend to mess with that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag in you returned html

```
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

This wont let the browser cache the page and user shall get the expired page on clicking back button, user need to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: this is not helpfull. still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also see the dicussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag) which talks about disabling form auto complete.